# python how to find the number of days in each month from Dec 2019 and forward between two date columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have two date columns 'StartDate' and 'EndDate'.  I want to find the number of days in each month between those two dates from Dec 2019 and forward ignoring any prior months of 2019 for calculation. StartDate and EndDate of each row can span across 2 years with overlapped months and Date columns can also be empty.

Sample Data:

```
df = {'Id': ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7', '8'],
      'Item': ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G', 'H'],
        'StartDate': ['2019-12-10', '2019-12-01', '2019-10-01', '2020-01-01', '2019-03-01','2019-03-01','2019-10-01', ''],
        'EndDate': ['2020-02-21' ,'2020-01-01','2020-08-31','2020-01-30','2019-12-31','2019-12-31','2020-08-31', '']
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(df,columns= ['Id', 'Item','StartDate','EndDate'])
```

Expected O/P:

[image: 1]

The below solution works partially works.

```
df['StartDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['StartDate'])
df['EndDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EndDate'])

def days_of_month(x):
    s = pd.date_range(*x, freq='D').to_series()
    return s.resample('M').count().rename(lambda x: x.month)

df1 = df[['StartDate', 'EndDate']].apply(days_of_month, axis=1).fillna(0)

df_final = df[['StartDate', 'EndDate']].join([df['StartDate'].dt.year.rename('Year'), df1])
```

Comment: The second to last line of your output seems wrong for the first few columns. Also Dec 19 for your first row is inconsistent with how you count the rest of the dates. I.e. if 12/1 to the end of December is 31 days, then 12/10 to the end of december should be 22 days

Comment: Also Feb 2020 has 29 days, so that entire column seems wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df.join(df.dropna(axis=0,how='any')
         .apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x['StartDate'],x['EndDate'], freq='D')
         .to_frame().resample('M').count().loc['2019-12-01':].unstack(), axis=1)[0].fillna(0))
```

Output:

```
 Id Item  StartDate    EndDate  2019-12-31 00:00:00  2020-01-31 00:00:00  2020-02-29 00:00:00  2020-03-31 00:00:00  2020-04-30 00:00:00  2020-05-31 00:00:00  2020-06-30 00:00:00  2020-07-31 00:00:00  2020-08-31 00:00:00
0  1    A 2019-12-10 2020-02-21                 22.0                 31.0                 21.0                  0.0                  0.0                  0.0                  0.0                  0.0                  0.0
1  2    B 2019-12-01 2020-01-01                 31.0                  1.0                  0.0                  0.0                  0.0                  0.0                  0.0                  0.0                  0.0
2  3    C 2019-10-01 2020-08-31                 31.0                 31.0                 29.0                 31.0                 30.0                 31.0                 30.0                 31.0                 31.0
3  4    D 2020-01-01 2020-01-30                  0.0                 30.0                  0.0                  0.0                  0.0                  0.0                  0.0                  0.0                  0.0
4  5    E 2019-03-01 2019-12-31                 31.0                  0.0                  0.0                  0.0                  0.0                  0.0                  0.0                  0.0                  0.0
5  6    F 2019-03-01 2019-12-31                 31.0                  0.0                  0.0                  0.0                  0.0                  0.0                  0.0                  0.0                  0.0
6  7    G 2019-10-01 2020-08-31                 31.0                 31.0                 29.0                 31.0                 30.0                 31.0                 30.0                 31.0                 31.0
7  8    H        NaT        NaT                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

We'll create two large DataFrames, one with the start of each month and another with the end of each month. We'll then clip them accordingly which leaves us with a simple subtraction. Since you want to include the end dates, we need to add 1 day, and we clean up any negative dates, which should be 0.

```
import pandas as pd

df_s = pd.DataFrame([pd.date_range('2019-12-01', '2020-12-01', freq='MS').to_numpy()],
                     index=df.index)
df_e = df_s + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(1)

df_s = df_s.clip(lower=pd.to_datetime(df.StartDate), axis=0)
df_e = df_e.clip(upper=pd.to_datetime(df.EndDate), axis=0)

res = ((df_e - df_s) + pd.to_timedelta(1, 'd')).clip(lower=pd.to_timedelta(0, 'd'))
res.columns = pd.period_range(start='2019-12', end='2020-12', freq='M')

# So int or float
for col in res.columns:
    res[col] = res[col].dt.days

df = pd.concat([df, res], axis=1)
```

---

```
  Id Item   StartDate     EndDate  2019-12  2020-01  2020-02  2020-03  2020-04  2020-05  2020-06  2020-07  2020-08  2020-09  2020-10  2020-11  2020-12
0  1    A  2019-12-10  2020-02-21     22.0     31.0     21.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
1  2    B  2019-12-01  2020-01-31     31.0     31.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
2  3    C  2019-10-01  2020-08-31     31.0     31.0     29.0     31.0     30.0     31.0     30.0     31.0     31.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
3  4    D  2020-01-01  2020-01-30      0.0     30.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
4  5    E  2019-03-01  2019-12-31     31.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
5  6    F  2019-03-01  2019-12-31     31.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
6  7    G  2019-10-01  2020-08-31     31.0     31.0     29.0     31.0     30.0     31.0     30.0     31.0     31.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
7  8    H                              NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach, creating the whole day list, and compute the overlap with broadcasting:

```
dates = pd.date_range('2019-12-01', '2020-12-31', freq='D').values

(pd.DataFrame((df.StartDate.values <= dates[:,None]) 
              & (df.EndDate.values >= dates[:,None]),
             index=dates)
   .resample('M')
   .sum()
   .T
)
```

Output:

```
      2019-12-31 00:00:00    2020-01-31 00:00:00    2020-02-29 00:00:00    2020-03-31 00:00:00    2020-04-30 00:00:00    2020-05-31 00:00:00    2020-06-30 00:00:00    2020-07-31 00:00:00    2020-08-31 00:00:00    2020-09-30 00:00:00    2020-10-31 00:00:00    2020-11-30 00:00:00    2020-12-31 00:00:00
--  ---------------------  ---------------------  ---------------------  ---------------------  ---------------------  ---------------------  ---------------------  ---------------------  ---------------------  ---------------------  ---------------------  ---------------------  ---------------------
 0                     22                     31                     21                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0
 1                     31                      1                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0
 2                     31                     31                     29                     31                     30                     31                     30                     31                     31                      0                      0                      0                      0
 3                      0                     30                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0
 4                     31                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0
 5                     31                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0
 6                     31                     31                     29                     31                     30                     31                     30                     31                     31                      0                      0                      0                      0
 7                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the same code, add `coerce` to `to_datetime` and `dropna` and change in the `rename` part

```
df['StartDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['StartDate'], errors='coerce')
df['EndDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EndDate'], errors='coerce')

def days_of_month(x):
    s = pd.date_range(*x, freq='D').to_series()
    return s.resample('M').count().rename(lambda x: x.to_period(freq='M'))

df1 = (df[['StartDate', 'EndDate']].dropna().apply(days_of_month, axis=1)
                                   .reindex(df.index).fillna(0))

df_final = df.join(df1)

Out[1205]:
  Id Item  StartDate    EndDate  2019-03  2019-04  2019-05  2019-06  2019-07  \
0  1    A 2019-12-10 2020-02-21      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
1  2    B 2019-12-01 2020-01-01      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
2  3    C 2019-10-01 2020-08-31      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
3  4    D 2020-01-01 2020-01-30      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
4  5    E 2019-03-01 2019-12-31     31.0     30.0     31.0     30.0     31.0
5  6    F 2019-03-01 2019-12-31     31.0     30.0     31.0     30.0     31.0
6  7    G 2019-10-01 2020-08-31      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
7  8    H        NaT        NaT      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0

   2019-08  2019-09  2019-10  2019-11  2019-12  2020-01  2020-02  2020-03  \
0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0     22.0     31.0     21.0      0.0
1      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0     31.0      1.0      0.0      0.0
2      0.0      0.0     31.0     30.0     31.0     31.0     29.0     31.0
3      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0     30.0      0.0      0.0
4     31.0     30.0     31.0     30.0     31.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
5     31.0     30.0     31.0     30.0     31.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
6      0.0      0.0     31.0     30.0     31.0     31.0     29.0     31.0
7      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0

   2020-04  2020-05  2020-06  2020-07  2020-08
0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
1      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
2     30.0     31.0     30.0     31.0     31.0
3      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
4      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
5      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
6     30.0     31.0     30.0     31.0     31.0
7      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
```

Comment: Thank you @Andy L